# Disable copyWith for a nested Freezed Object

Tags: flutter, freezed, flutter-freezed

I'm using the [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package to create Objects. I want to disable the `copyWith` of a nested @Freezed Object. See the following example:

```
@freezed
class RenewLeaseState with _$RenewLeaseState {
  const factory RenewLeaseState({
    @Default(BlocScreenNavigator()) BlocScreenNavigator navigator,
  }) = _RenewLeaseState;
}

@Freezed(copyWith: false)
class BlocScreenNavigator with _$BlocScreenNavigator {
  const factory BlocScreenNavigator({
    @Default(RenewLeaseScreen.init) RenewLeaseScreen screen,
    @Default(false) bool isPop,
  }) = _BlocScreenNavigator;
}
```

My build fails since the `RenewLeaseState` generated object tries to call the `copyWith` function of `BlocScreenNavigator`, which is disabled.

> lib/renew_lease/cubit/renew_lease_cubit.freezed.dart:56:3: Error: Type
> '$BlocScreenNavigatorCopyWith' not found.
> $BlocScreenNavigatorCopyWith<$Res> get navigator;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/renew_lease/cubit/renew_lease_cubit.freezed.dart:116:3: Error:
> Type '$BlocScreenNavigatorCopyWith' not found.
> $BlocScreenNavigatorCopyWith<$Res> get navigator {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/renew_lease/cubit/renew_lease_cubit.freezed.dart:142:3: Error:
> Type '$BlocScreenNavigatorCopyWith' not found.
> $BlocScreenNavigatorCopyWith<$Res> get navigator;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/renew_lease/cubit/renew_lease_cubit.freezed.dart:117:12: Error:
> The method '$BlocScreenNavigatorCopyWith' isn't defined for the class
> '_$RenewLeaseStateCopyWithImpl<$Res>'.
>
> - '_$RenewLeaseStateCopyWithImpl' is from 'package:tenant_app/renew_lease/cubit/renew_lease_cubit.dart'
>   ('lib/renew_lease/cubit/renew_lease_cubit.dart'). Try correcting the
>   name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
>   '$BlocScreenNavigatorCopyWith'.
>   return $BlocScreenNavigatorCopyWith<$Res>(_value.navigator, (value) {
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I need to keep the nested Object `copyWith` disabled to force the user to assign its parameters.

Is it a Freezed issue? What is the workaround in that situation?

### Update

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/747) on GitHub.